# Pourquoi dit-on « c'est juste magnifique » ?

Tags: expressions, adverbes, anglicismes

J'entends de plus en plus à la télé (Pékin Express par exemple), cette expression:

*C'est juste {magnifique, incroyable, le plus grand XY}.*

Est-ce que cette expression a un nom ? Je sens que c'est une sorte d'antinomie entre *juste* qui tend à banaliser, et l'adjectif qui suit, souvent grandiose, dont le but est de ..? (je sèche)

Est-ce qu'elle a été importée de l'anglais, où l'on entend plus souvent *That's just ...* ? Je n'ai pas d'exemple en tête, mais je ne suis pas choqué quand je l'entends en anglais.

**Edit:**  *juste* ne prendrait-il pas le même sens que dans *c'est juste* quand il signifie *c'est vrai* ? Étant donné qu'on l'entend maintenant dans bon nombre d'émissions non scriptées, je me demande vraiment si les gens qui l'utilisent ne pensent pas plutôt à l'utiliser à la place de *tout à fait*, ou *vraiment* ?

Comment: Je crois (mais je n'ai pas de preuve ou de source) que c'est effectivement une expression récente, probablement calquée de l'anglais. Traditionnellement on aurait plutôt dit « c'est tout simplement magnifique » (qui a le même genre d'antinomie, juste avec un autre mot).

Comment: C'est aussi mon sentiment. Il y a aussi la construction un peu inhabituelle *rien moins que* : « C'est rien moins qu'exceptionnel. ». Il me semble que l'effet de contraste est du même type, même s'il est beaucoup plus rare que son équivalent anglais *nothing short of*.

Comment: Je trouve juste ca extrêmement énervant... effet de mode comment il y en a tant, vivement que ca se termine :-)

Comment: @Bartdude C'est difficilement quantifiable, mais j'ai l'impression de l'entendre beaucoup moins ces derniers temps.

Answer (score 10):

Cette expression ressemble à une [litote<sup>wiki</sup>](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litote).

Derrière une apparente modestie (l'emploi du mot *« juste »*) se cache en réalité l'intention du locuteur d'augmenter le sens de ce qui va suivre.

Comment: Je me permet de signaler que l'emploi de "juste" de cette façon, pour donner une emphase à ce qui suit fait partie du langage parlé au quotidien et n'est pas adapté aux échanges plus formels.

Answer (score 4):

En l’occurrence (tout en étant effectivement une litote, comme le note Stamm), je crois que c'est essentiellement une forme plus courte de "C'est tout simplement...".

Answer (score 2):

Je pense qu'il s'agit de la traduction directe de l'anglais *just*. Mais en anglais le sens est plutôt « vraiment » ou « tout à fait » alors qu'en français le sens est « simplement ». *Just* en anglais est d'une certaine façon un « faux-ami » et la traduction mot à mot est pour moi une erreur. Mais l'usage commande et on utilisera ce mot tant que durera sa mode. 
Il y a pas mal d'années s'était répandue la mode un peu pédante de dire « complètement » à la place de « oui je suis d'accord », elle a passé en 5-6 ans.

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression est représentative du laisser-aller que l'on entend tous les jours.
Il est dommage que cela se banalise.

Il ne faut pas employer l'adverbe "juste" dans le sens qu'indique le titre de ton article.

Explication ici : http://lemondedufrancais.com/2012/03/05/utilisation-de-juste-en-francais/

Je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'une simple traduction littérale de l'anglais. A mon avis, l'idée de faire précéder un superlatif (comme "incroyable", "magnifique", ...) par l'adverbe "juste", qui tend à banaliser, rendre anodin ce superlatif vient d'Alain Manoukian, dans l'émission Nouvelle Star :
"Adrien, c'est juste grandiose, ce que tu viens de chanter!"

Dans une autre émission, The Voice, c'est Florent Pagny qui use et abuse de "Juste incroyable", "Juste stupéfiant", "juste hallucinant", etc.

Ces deux émissions présentant des similarités et se positionnant régulièrement parmi les plus regardées de la télévision française, le public étant le même, l'impact de cette expression utilisant "juste" a été immédiat et de diffusion large et rapide.

Aujourd'hui, une majorité de jeunes utilisent cette affreuse association, tout en ne percevant pas l'atteinte qu'ils profèrent à la langue française.

Il se trouve que "just" est très utilisé en anglais, sans que cela ne soit une erreur syntaxique ou grammaticale dans cette langue.
A partir de là, beaucoup ont bâti l'explication de l'usage de ["juste" + "adjectif"] sur une simple traduction littérale de l'anglais.

On peut utiliser "juste" à bon escient : "C'est juste à 5mn d'ici", "Au niveau financier, je suis un peu juste ce mois-ci", "Je voudrais juste que tu me rendes un service".

Mais en aucun cas, on associe "juste" à un adjectif qualificatif. Quelle horreur! Cela m'écorche les oreilles.

Comment: Pourrais-tu argumenter sur les jugements de valeur (*affreuse* / *horreur* / *écorche les oreilles*) ? Nous avons vraisemblablement la même appréciation pour la valeur artistique des personnes que tu cites mais... pourquoi cet usage est-il problématique selon toi ? Simplement parce qu'il emprunte à l'anglais, ou est-ce autre chose ?

Comment: Sans forcément pouvoir le "just"-ifier, je ressens aussi cet usage comme profondément agressif. Il a tendance à me mettre les nerfs en pelote.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense juste que cette expression est juste un effet de mode, il serait juste d'employer un autre mot mais juste aussi de ne pas employer de mot : on peut juste dire "c'est magnifique !" au lieu de "c'est juste magnifique". Ceux qui emploient cette expression sont peut-être juste un peu justes en français ;-) ou juste influencé par la mode ou juste encore par les série tv américaines doublées qui emploient juste le mot juste à toutes les sauces car traduits juste à la va-vite. Pour ma part j'évite juste cette tournure de phrase. (Vous voyez que c'est juste agaçant ;-)

Comment: This is just brilliant. (and obnoxious too, yes). Hmmm. Let me guess. Stephane ? Evpok ?